# How can I save two variables with jQuery's .data() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I execute the following script, only one value is displayed in the alert:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var num = 15;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            $('<tr style="background-color: aqua" id = ' + i + '></tr>').appendTo("table");
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                num++;
                $('<td id ='+num+'></td>').appendTo("#"+i);
                $('<button>S</button>').data("field", i, j).appendTo("#" + num);
            }
        }
        $('td').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var d = $(this);
            alert(d.data("field"));  // here alert shows one variable
        });
    }
</script>
```

How can I store two values in the element's data? Maybe I can send an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them as `object` or `array` .

```
 $('<button>S</button>').data("field", [i,j] ).appendTo("#" + num);
```

and alert them using

```
alert( d.data("field").join(',') );  // here alert shows one variable
```

as per comment  "*Calling join(",") is not actually necessary, the override of toString() implemented by arrays already performs this operation.*" . so you can all simply

```
alert( d.data("field") );
```

check this on http://jsfiddle.net/xhPjh/

Comment: Calling `join(",")` is not actually necessary, the override of `toString()` implemented by arrays already performs this operation. `alert(d.data("field"))` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The data you store using the jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method can be an object. So you can store the values this way:

```
$('<button>S</button>').data("field", { i: i, j: j});
```

And read them out again like this:

```
var d = $(this),
    field = d.data("field");
alert(field.i);
alert(field.j);
```

You should also look into using jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method instead of `window.onload`.